# Modify constructor parameter values before calling base class constructor

Tags: c++

I have following class hierarchy:

```
class Base { // This class cannot be modified
public:
  Base(int a, int b, int c) {
     if ( a == 100 && b == 200 && c < 100  ) // whatever condition
       throw "Error!";
  }
};

class Derived : public Base { // this class can be modified
public:
   Derived(int a, int b, int c) : Base(a, b, c) {}
};
```

class Derived is used in many places in code, so it cannot be replaced with some kind of factory function.

now the question is if there is some construct that would allow me to fix a,b,c values before calling Base constructor?

I know I can use functions like:

```
   Derived(int a, int b, int c) : Base(FixA(a), FixB(b), FixC(c)) {}

   int FixA(int a) { /*fix a value*/ return a; }
   int FixB(int b) { /*fix b value*/ return b; }
   int FixC(int c) { /*fix c value*/ return c; }
```

but it wont allow me to set correct values in case when a b c values are dependent like in above Base class c-tor example.

I was thinking of extending this to:

```
   Derived(int a, int b, int c) : Base(FixA(a,b,c), FixB(a,b,c), FixC(a,b,c)) {}

   int FixA(int a, int& b, int& c) { /*fix a b c values*/ return a; }
   int FixB(int& a, int b, int& c) { /*fix a b c values*/ return b; }
   int FixC(int& a, int& b, int c) { /*fix a b c values*/ return c; }
```

I suppose there should also be some kind of flag indicating that fix was already done. I am not sure if this is actually correct c++.

I know the best solution is to actually catch exception.

Comment: If you know the best solution already, then why don't you implement it? Is there some other restriction you are not mentioning here? Also, couldn't you just check the parameters before calling the constructor of `Derived`?

Comment: The three `Fix` functions are evaluated in an unspecified order, so taking the arguments by reference looks tricky.

Comment: You already provided some solutions, whats wrong with them? And What exactly do you want to fix with these values before calling base constructor? Please tell your exact problem.

Comment: The exact problem is that Base class is ATL::CTime that throws if time to set is invalid value, like pre: 1970:1:1 12:0:0. I would like to at least protect agains cases when value to set is 1970:1:1 0:0:0. I am not sure if this solutions are valid (mostly the second one), code schould work on various compilers VS2005, gcc. Checking parameters would be preferable, but code base is very large.

Comment: :) OK - using gcc I wont probably be using ATL so only VS2005+ is valid compiler

Comment: Why not use another CTime constructor? There are plenty, taking __time64_t time, for example. Then you can write a single __time64_t Fix(int a, int b, int c) and pass it to CTime.

Comment: @Steed: I was thinking about this but I want this fix to be as small as possible, I was also interested in how to do it using some general c++ construction

Comment: Deriving from Time class smells to me. Are you sure you want to create a class that is-a time (inheritance) not has-a time (composition)?

Comment: This is a legacy code, I am not creating this class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider interposing a class between `Derived` and `Base`:

```
class Derived: public UnpackToBase {
public:
    Derived(int a, int b, int c): UnpackToBase(FixParameters(a, b, c))

class UnpackToBase: public Base {
public:
    UnpackToBase(FixParameters params): Base(params.a, params.b, params.c)

struct FixParameters {
    int a, b, c;
    FixParameters(int a, int b, int c): a(a), b(b), c(c) {
         // do stuff
    }
```

In C++11 you can use a *delegating constructor* of `Derived`:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    Derived(int a, int b, int c): Derived(FixParameters(a, b, c)) { }
    Derived(FixParameters params): Base(params.a, params.b, params.c) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the singleton pattern to resolve this. Please see the code below. Here the order of initialization of the construction initialization list doesn't matter. However, I'm doubtful, if this can be called elegant.

```
class Base 
{ 
    // This class cannot be modified 
public:   Base(int a, int b, int c) 
          {      
              if ( a == 100 && b == 200 && c < 100  ) // whatever condition
                  throw "Error!";   
          } 
};  

class Validator
{
public:

    static Validator& instance(int a_in, int b_in, int c_in)
    {
        static Validator v(a_in,b_in,c_in);

        return v;
    }



    int& a(){ return m_a;}
    int& b(){ return m_b;}
    int& c(){ return m_c;}

private:

    Validator(int a_in, int b_in, int c_in) : m_a(a_in), m_b(b_in), m_c(c_in)
    {
        //  perform validation and modify the members
        //  Example validation
        if(m_a > 0 && m_b > 0)
        {
            m_c = 0;
        }
    }

    int m_a;
    int m_b;
    int m_c;
};

class Derived : public Base 
{ 
    // this class can be modified 
public:    
    Derived(int a, int b, int c) : Base(Validator::instance(a, b, c).a(), Validator::instance(a, b, c).b(), Validator::instance(a, b, c).c())
    {} 
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Derived d(1,2,3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have a problem with *hacking* what you have to make something weird happen, so why not use *good 'ol **macros***..

```
#define FIX_ME(x) //do something
Derived(int a, int b, int c) : Base(FIX_ME(a), FIX_ME(b), FIX_ME(c)) {}
```

Comment: This can work if he has same fixes for each variable (a,b,c) but if he has different fixes for each variable, then you have to make 3 macros.

Comment: Yep. And I'd probably rather it over `Derived(int a, int b, int c) : Base(FixA(a,b,c), FixB(a,b,c), FixC(a,b,c)) {}`. It's a _bad_ answer for a _bad_ question. Trying to bend and break existing code because of a dodgy design decisions is never going to be pretty.

Comment: :D ,  he must tell his actual requirement so that we can help him.

Comment: i have added more info in question comments